# How to make UITextView not editable and dont want keyboard to showup

Tags: iphone, uitextview

In a `UITextView` have a text which is for readonly and dont want any userinteraction at all means dont want text to be edited and even dont want keyboard to showup. I want to make `UITextView` scrollable.

Right now what happening is that it is not scrollable and the content is editable and keyboard shows up and bottom wall of the border is not showing. If anyone can help me with this issue. Will appreciate it so much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Set the [`editable` / `isEditable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618616-iseditable) property to `NO` / `false`.

Swift 3, 4:

```
textView.isEditable = false
```

Swift 1, 2:

```
textView.editable = false
```

Objective-C:

```
textView.editable = NO;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
textView.editable = NO;
```

It's mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html).

And about the scrolling; Your UITextView will scroll when the content size exceeds the frame size of your UITextView.

Comment: self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 415)];
    
        self.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    
        self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-BoldItalic" size:16];

Comment: That looks like a really large frame. I don't see the text you are putting in the textview but I can guess that your textView frame is larger than the content size (size of the text). At this point it would be best to attach a screenshot of what your textview looks like.

Answer (score 3):

```
textview.editable = false // for swift language
textview.selectable = false //

// override textview delegates
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: once you set the editable property to false, there is no need to override the "ShouldBeginEditing" method.

Comment: He just gave two methods to accomplish the target. @UmarJamil

Comment: With *Swift 4*
textview.isEditable = false
textview.isSelectable = false

Answer (score 2):

you can also set the behavior through storyboard. just uncheck the 'editable' like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Update Swift 3+

`editable` and `selectable` have been renamed to `isEditable` and `isSelectable`

```
textView.isEditable = false
textView.isSelectable = false
```

---

> - [isEditable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618616-iseditable)
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the receiver is editable. The default value of this property is true.
>
> ```
>  var isEditable: Bool { get set }
> ```
>
> - [isSelectable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618627-isselectable)
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the receiver is selectable. This property controls the ability of the user to select content and interact with URLs and text attachments. The default value is true.
>
> ```
>  var isSelectable: Bool { get set }
> ```